# I am facing issue regarding the compilation of grpc cpp code in visual studio

Tags: c++

I made a sample code for working learning grpc in cpp and compiled it in visual studio 2019. I keep on getting an error

```
port_platform.h(53,1): error C1189:  #error:      "Please compile grpc with _WIN32_WINNT of at least 0x600 (aka Windows Vista)"
```

Comment: What is your windows version?

Comment: You need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` to the suggested value

Comment: i tried adding _WIN32_WINNT  but still the issue isarising

Comment: i am having windows 7

Comment: Try to `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601` before the include file that issues the error. See also: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18928

Answer (score 1):

Also ran into this today.  Solved it by manually editing these two files:

- `C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\grpc\impl\codegen\port_platform.h`
- `C:\src\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\grpc\impl\codegen\port_platform.h`

...to insert this text around line 32 in both of the files:

```
#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(WIN64) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
+#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

I didn't come up with this solution.  Found it here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18928#issuecomment-494171557